# Filter by checkbox show/hide target divs jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble targetting the divs I need to show/hide when my jQuery runs.

I need to hide `<div class="grid-cell>` otherwise flexbox won't display correctly once the div's are hidden.

I'm having trouble getting it to hit the correct divs and it's not working now after changing my code a bit.

https://jsfiddle.net/s1e93j92/6/

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="High" data-category-type="high">High
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="low" data-category-type="low" > Low
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="low" data-category-name="bread" > bread

<div class="wrap">
<div class="grid grid--flexcells grid--gutters grid--1of2">        
    <div class="grid-cell">
        <div class="box">
            <div id="categories" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="low">
                <a href="#">
                <div class="image"><img src="#"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="grid-cell">
        <div class="box">
             <div id="Categories" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="bread">
                <a href="#">
                <div class="image"><img src="#"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div class="grid-cell">
        <div class="box">
            <div id="Categories" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="low">
                <a href="#">
                <div class="image"><img src="#"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                     <div class="grid-cell">
        <div class="box">
            <div id="Categories" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="bread">
                <a href="#">
                <div class="image"><img src="#"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrap{width:80%; height:200px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
.grid { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.grid--1of2 > .grid-cell { flex: 0 0 50%; }
.image{width:100%; height:100px; border:1px solid #ff00ff}

 $('.checkbox ').on('click', function (e) {


var $this = $(this),
    $links = $('.checkbox');

if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
    $this.removeClass('selected');
} else {
    $this.addClass('selected');
}

 var selectedDivs = $('.box > categories > a > div').hide();
 var anySelectedCheckbox = false;
 $.each($links, function (k, v) {

$this = $(v);

if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
    anySelectedCheckbox = true;
    var cat = $this.data('categoryType');
    var nam = $this.data('categoryName');
    selectedDivs = selectedDivs.filter('[data-category-type="'+cat+'"], [data-category-name="'+nam+'"]');
}

});
selectedDivs.show();

if(!anySelectedCheckbox) {
$('.box > div').show();

}


});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? As it stands, this question is a little too vague to answer.

Comment: I have managed to solve this by changing var selectedDivs = $('.grid-cell').hide(); and modifying my html code

Comment: my solution is probably cleaner, so go accept it and vote me up.  :)  it took a little time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment suggests, it's not perfectly clear what you're trying to do, but I think I got it.  I didn't make any changes to your HTML or CSS.  Just modified your JavaScript a little.

```
$('.checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $links = $('.checkbox');

    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        $this.removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $this.addClass('selected');
    }

    $('.box').hide();
    if ($(".checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
        // any one is checked
        $.each($links, function (k, v) {
            $this = $(v);
            if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
                anySelectedCheckbox = true;
                var cat = $this.data('categoryType');
                var nam = $this.data('categoryName');
                $('.box:has(div[data-category-type="' + cat + '"],div[data-category-name="+nam+"] )').show();
            }

        });
    } else {
        // none is checked
        $('.box').show();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yzyyqqey/

Comment: close enough, does exactly what I want ut I've realised I need to hide `grid-cell` to make it work correctly. Thansk1

Comment: Much cleaner and easier to understand. OP should consider using this solution if only to improve readability. You've got my upvote.